# Facebook-messenger-bot. How to implement checkboxes?

Tags: facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

Please share the experience with how to implement checkboxes in Facebook messenger bot.
There is an idea to change the color of the button by clicking on it. But I have not found a way to edit the buttons.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today the only way to do checkboxes is to use the webview https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/messenger-extension